# How can I grant access of my database to a user with a certain username and password which I am not using?

Tags: java, mysql, eclipse, servlets, jdbc

I am working on a web app using java Servlets on eclipse. I have created a database in MySQL and what I want to do now is that I want my this database to be accessible with a different username and password as well, so that other users login with the 2nd username and password and my personal username and password remains unexposed and hidden.

I have Googled but am not getting satisfying answer, I would appreciate a solution which can run on my MySQL Workbench 6.0.

Thanks in advance for your time!

Comment: Do you mean to ask how to create a username/password combo in mySQL?

Comment: @MarsAtomic, yes but a different username/password than my current, and want both of these to work on my database! I need 2nd username/password because I want my database to be available to all other my colleagues without knowing my personal username/password!

Comment: Try getting a new Google. My Google promptly returned [this](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/adding-users.html)

Comment: yea I saw it, but what do I write in place of localhost in this:
mysql> CREATE USER 'monty'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'some_pass';

Comment: moreover, do you know how to check who and how many users can access my database or to whom my database access is provided?
Sorry I am new to this database stuff!

Comment: Err... localhost is the name of the machine your database is on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a second user using the following command

```
CREATE USER 'username'@'hostname' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
```

After creating the user give the access to the particular database using the this command

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON DB_NAME.* To 'username'@'hostname' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
```

Comment: great and is there a way to see all those users who have been granted all privileges?

Comment: To check the privileges for particular database check this command select * from information_schema.SCHEMA_PRIVILEGES where TABLE_SCHEMA LIKE 'DATABASE_NAME%';

Answer (score 1):

To get a list of users on your mySQL database, try using:

```
SELECT User FROM mysql.user;
```

Comment: yea PERFECT this is showing, now the problem is that I provided privilege to user by username = "as_app" but when I am trying to connect the database via eclipse jdbc, I am getting the following error:

Access denied for user 'as_app'@'%' to database 'activationserver'